# Add multiple column based on another column

Tags: c#, sql

```
PART JAN19 FEB19 MAR19 APR19----DEC19  JAN19_TYPE  FEB19_TYPE  MAR19_TYPE  APR19_TYPE----DEC19_TYPE 
A     1     2     2     5        10       SH          SH          SH          SL        SL
B     1     2     2     5        10       SL          SL          SL           SL        SL
C     1     2     2     5        10       N           N           N            SH        N
D     1     2     2     5        10       SH          SH          SH           SL        SH
```

I want to add sale of months based on conditions.

if three consecutive SH is exist then add SALE of

1. Check DEC_TYPE column.
   If it is SL, then add all column which have "TYPE" SL otherwise 0.

   e.g. for part A.
   three consecutive SH is exist.

   DEC19_TYPE is SL  and SL in of APR19_TYPE and DEC19_TYPE
   then add sale APR19, DEC19

Comment: from where are you trying to add is it php code or c# from which you are trying to hit this sql db.!!

Comment: c# code, actually i have only sale in table after many more formulas i alter new column "type" and update values as SL,N,SH to particular month

Comment: then you can manipulate the data in c# level that's the easy way why not do this way.

Comment: it's used inside the  procedure. so  can't use  in c# level